# Supervisord Hangs/Hungs on the Background after 10 minutes

Tags: python, supervisord

Somehow supervisord hangs/hungs 10 minutes after we do `service supervisor start`. Scripts initiated by supervisod still appears on the background as running but not functioning anymore. Any idea what could be the issue? Our current workaround was to install a cron job to restart supervisord every 10 minutes. supervisord version is 3.1.4 and python is 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

you can run your scripts command in the shell, don't start it in supervisord . and wait 10 minutes to see if it work well. you can also write some log in your script.I use supervisord in many projects and almost problem is command error or code error.